# std::function argument to receives any number of arguments

Tags: c++

I've defined a template function that receives std::function. and I want to send a member function. that works fine (example: test2)
How can I rewrite it so std::function receives any number of argument? (test3)

another question - can this be done without the std::bind?

```
struct Cls
{
    int foo() { return 11; }
};

template<typename T>
void test2(std::function<T()> func)
{}

template<typename T, typename... Args> 
void test3(std::function<T(Args... args)> func, Args&&... args)
{}

int main()
{
    Cls ccc;

    test2<int>(std::bind(&Cls::foo, ccc));  // Ok
    test3<int>(std::bind(&Cls::foo, ccc));  // does not compile!
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
no matching function for call to ‘test3<int>(std::_Bind_helper<false, int (Cls::*)(), Cls&>::type)’ 34 | test3<int>(std::bind(&Cls::foo, ccc));
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message.

Comment: In C++ 20, you can use `bind_forward()`, which doesn't require the exact amount of arguments. Or, since C++11, you can use a lambda and then call your overloaded function however you need it

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘test3<int>(std::_Bind_helper<false, int (Cls::*)(), Cls&>::type)’
   34 |     test3<int>(std::bind(&Cls::foo, ccc));

Comment: test3 runs it, of course, but also does all kind of other stuff

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that `std::bind` doesn't return a `std::function`, it returns some unspecified callable type.  Therefore the compiler can't deduce the correct template parameters for `test3`.

The way to work around that is to make your function accept any callable type instead of trying to accept a `std::function`:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void test3(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{}
```

This will work with a `std::bind` result, a lambda, a raw function pointer, a `std::function`, etc.

---

> can this be done without the std::bind?

Sort of.  A pointer to a member function always requires an instance of the class to be called on.  You can avoid needing to explicitly `std::bind` the instance into a wrapper by passing it as a parameter and using the `std::invoke` helper to call the function.  For pointers to member functions, `std::invoke` treats the first parameter as the object to call the member on.

For example:

```
struct Cls
{
    int foo() { return 11; }
};

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void test3(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void bar(double, int) {}

int main()
{
    Cls ccc;

    test3(bar, 3.14, 42);  // Works with a raw function pointer
    test3(&Cls::foo, ccc); // Works with a pointer to member function
    test3([](int){}, 42);  // Works with other callable types, like a lambda
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8896fb6c542f2ed6)

Answer (score 0):

> can this be done without the std::bind?

Yes this can be done without `std::bind` as shown below.

```
struct Cls
{
    int foo() { return 11; }

    int func(int, double)
    {
        return 4;
    }
};


template<typename className, typename... Param,typename Ret, typename... Args>  
void test4(Ret (className::*ptrFunc)(Param... param),className& Object, Args... args)
{
    (Object.*ptrFunc)(args...);

    //std::invoke(ptrFunc, Object, args...); //WITH C++17

}
int main()
{
    Cls ccc;

   
    test4(&Cls::foo, ccc); //works 
    test4(&Cls::func, ccc, 4,5); //works 
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kvqj1eMvK)

---

With C++17 we can use `std::invoke` to replace the call `(Object.*ptrFunc)(args...);` with:

```
std::invoke(ptrFunc, Object, args...); //WITH C++17
```

[C++17 `std::invoke` demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9zfa9Eeba)