# A "pointer" to any type of function

Tags: c++

is there any mechanism with elegant API to handle functions of any type?

I mean a class that automagically detects type of a function (its return type, arguments, if it is a class member, a const etc), something that I could easily use to handle any kind of events, like in the example below:

```
class Abc
{
    public:
        void aFunc() { std::cout << "a()" << std::endl; }
        void cFunc(int x, char y) { std::cout << "c(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl; }
};

void bFunc(int x) { std::cout << "b(" << x << ")" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    Abc abc;
    EventHandler a = abc.aFunc;
    EventHandler b = bFunc;
    EventHandler c = abc::cFunc;

    a();
    b(123);
    c(456789, 'f');

    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The std::function and std::bind can be used internally, but the bind should be done automatically.

Comment: Is this something you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652242/stdfunction-argument-to-receives-any-number-of-arguments ?

Comment: `abc.aFunc;` is wrong, you might want `[&](){ return abc.aFunc();};` or `std::bind(&Abc::aFunc, &abc)`. Similar issue for `EventHandler c`.

Comment: What should happen on `c(1.0, std::string{});` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 it is not about the correctness. What I asked for is if there is any way to use the std::bind inside the constructor of EventHandler. The constructor should have probably a template and based on that template it first should be determined whether the function pointer type is a global function or a member function. Then based on this either std::bind should be used or not. All that I'd like to have is some elegant API that hides everything from programmer and therefore makes event handling much easier.

Comment: Extra error and misusage distracts from your real question. I suggest to fix them.

Comment: Does `EventHandler` have to be a class? `auto c = curry(&Abc::cFunc, &abc);` with `auto curry(auto... bound_args) { return [=](auto... args){ std::invoke(bound_args..., args...); } }` might do the job.

Comment: `abc::cFunc` is not a thing that exists. `Abc::cFunc` is, but then there's no reason to expect `c` to be able to know that you mean to call it from `abc`. Additional question: What if any of `aFunc`, `bFunc`, and `cFunc` are overloaded? Would the goal be for the `EventHandler` to just become aware of the entire overload set and figure out which one to invoke inside its `operator()`?

Comment: Does this question/answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74409037/12173376

Comment: Thanks @joergbrech, this is exactly the base for what I've been looking for.